# Possible to link to a specific element in Chrome Inspector?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

It would be useful to link to a specific element in the Chrome Inspector > Elements tab. For example, given a page with the following HTML:

```html
<div>
  <div id="box">A box element</div>
</div>
```

Is it possible to create a link to the `#id` element within the Chrome Inspector > Elements tab.

In other words, is it possible to create a link to a URL, open the Chrome Inspector and have the `#box` element automatically selected?

This could be done using the element's XPath, if there were some way to open Chrome Dev Tools via the URL, similar to `view-source:URL`.

Comment: Probably not. What do you intend to do with such a URL? (What do you think you can do with a view-source URL? You certainly can't link to it from a normal web page.)

Comment: It would be useful for debugging with others and education.

Comment: FWIW you can also type `inspect($('#id'))` in the devtools console (or `inspect($('#id')[0])` if the page has jQuery). Also, maybe someone wrote an extension panel for devtools already, or you can do it :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can right click on an element and choose either "Copy selector" or "Copy XPath". Pressing Cmd-F in the Elements panel will bring up a search bar with "Find by string, selector, or XPath", so you could use this to point someone to a specific element on a particular page.